# Changing counter value after different time intervals using PhP, Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a counter which changes its value after different time interval. I have written the code but dont know where I am doing wrong.
I used Ajax for this, but in different browser the value is changing randomly at same time interval.

counter2.php

```
`$sql="SELECT counter FROM counter";
 $result= mysql_query($sql);
 $rows=mysql_fetch_row($result);


 $counter=$rows[0];
 //$counter--;
 echo $counter;


 $sql2="UPDATE counter set counter= counter-1";
 $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
```

`
for ajax

countermain.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        var updateInterval = 1000; // 10 seconds, in milliseconds

        function updateCounter(){

            $.ajax({
            url: 'counter2.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(returnValue){
                    $('#alpha').text(returnValue);
                    setTimeout(updateCounter, 4000);
                }
        });
        }

      setInterval(updateCounter, updateInterval);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="alpha"></div>
```

let me know where and what I am doing wrong?